# duplicate herocard response in proactive bot

Tags: node.js, azure, botframework, azure-functions

I want to display an api response as a card, but the response duplicates - what am I doing wrong, is this a valid use of for hero card?

```
bot.dialog('/receipt', [
    function(session){
        bot.on('trigger', function (message) {
        var queuedMessage = message.value;
        var msg = new builder.Message()
             .address(queuedMessage.address)
             .attachments([
                new builder.HeroCard(session)
                    .title("Good news - I can book this for you:")
                    .subtitle("Customer: " + queuedMessage.name)
                    .images([
                        builder.CardImage.create(session, "")
                    ])
                    .buttons([
                        builder.CardAction.dialogAction(session, "bookIt", "", "Book it?"),
                        builder.CardAction.dialogAction(session, "help", "", "Start again?")
            ])
            ]);
            session.send(msg);
        })
    },  
]);
```

Comment: you should remove `bot.on('triger', ...)`.

Comment: but I need the card to only render once the queue is set with a response

Comment: how would I pick up a function response without using Trigger?

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by OmG in a comment: remove the `bot.on('trigger'`

It looks like you're trying to setup an `Azure Function` to trigger the bot to send a message: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-overview  That is not necessarily required in order to proactively send a user a message from a bot.

Please see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-proactive-messages for documentation on proactively sending messages.  Here are some samples in `node`: https://github.com/MicrosoftDX/botFramework-proactiveMessages/tree/master/node

Comment: thanks, but the azure function sets the value I want for the dialog, hence I am using it as trigger. Is this not best approach? The documentation only shows how to start dialog for Get, am struggling to make that work for my use case though?

Comment: Please explain more about your "use case".

Comment: I'm capturing some parameters- sending them sending them to an azure function, which calls an ML service and adds the response to a queue. I want this event to trigger a dialog (with a hero card)

Comment: Maybe post the code you've written to call the azure function.

Comment: this? var queueSvc = azure.createQueueService(process.env.AzureWebJobsStorage);
   queueSvc.createQueueIfNotExists('bot-queue', function(err, result, response){
       if(!err){
           // Add the message to the queue
           var queueMessageBuffer = new Buffer(JSON.stringify(queuedMessage)).toString('base64');
           queueSvc.createMessage('bot-queue', queueMessageBuffer, function(err, result, response){

Comment: That doesn't come through very well in a comment.  Please update your answer with the code you're using to add the message to the queue.

Comment: How are you creating queuedMessage?

Comment: I'm creating queuedMessage in an azure function. This is working fine now - thanks for your help